# Using Enterprise Library for another website on same system to build Data Access Layer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5, enterprise-library

In my system, the data access layer of one of the website is build using the enterprise library. Now I am developing another [different] website. How can I use the enterprise library to create the data access layer?

I am very beginner to Enterprise Library?

How can I configure it for my website? Should I have to include the DLL? How it will take the connection string from the Web.Config file?

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with Ch.1 and 2 of the Enterprise Library [Developer's Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff953191%28PandP.50%29.aspx).